# Can't play mp4 video in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm new to Android development, I'm trying to play an MP4 video from the RAW folder but, although I likely read every answer here and browsed for hours on google, I couldn't make it work.

My current code is (called on the onCreate() method)

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_container);
int vID = getResources().getIdentifier("video1", "raw", getPackageName());
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + vID);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
vv.setMediaController(mc);
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
```

(now the video name is hardcoded, but it should be passed from the previous Intent; I wrote it to rule out the possibility of this being the problem)

In the LogCat I keep getting this error only:

```
Error (1,-2147483648)
```

which is a bit obscure for me (seems is related to a lot of things), while the app only alerts the "Can't play this video" message and that's all.

Do I need to try/catch some Exceptions to at least have a better error reporting? The code I'm using is equal to tens of others I found on the internet and here, all claiming it works fine (and plays in the Eclipse Emulator), and noone was using a try/catch; the Android Developer docs are quite hard to follow sometimes, so I don't really know where and how to put these (onPrepare()?).

The video file is called "video1.mp4", and is placed in res/raw folder; it's size is approx. 10.4 Mb and it's been encoded out of a high-res mov file (app is the Android equivalent to an Ipad version) into an 854 x 480 H.264 / AVC using the Arista Transcoder with Ubuntu 12.04. For what is worth, the converted video plays fine on my PC.

I'm developing on Eclipse Indigo, the app is targeted at tablet devices, and the emulated AVD is a 1280x800 mdpi tablet. I don't have a real device now (and won't for days), so I can't test if the problem is just on the emulator or not.

Unfortunately, the possibility of copying the file to an SD card is out of the question, same for fetching videos from a remote server: the app needs to ship with all the videos embedded (as per client's requirements) and I can't know if the device will have or not the SD card (nor I don't know which model it is)

Comment: What's your `android:minSdkVersion` in your app?? **Cause Api-11+ only ables to play H.264 encoded video. So please try above Api-11.**

Comment: Just give a try to use **`Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/raw/video1);`**

Comment: Already tried that too, same story. And yes, min SDK version is 11